# How can i work with the ASP.NET Update Panel?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

in my asp.net application i have two dropdownlist,if i select the first one's one value means automatically want to change the values of dropdown two,but its not working.here is my asp code.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="State"></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlState" runat="server" Height="23px" Width="195px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged"
                AutoPostBack="True">
                <asp:ListItem>--Select--</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Kerela</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Tamilnadu</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Karnataka</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="District"></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDistrict" runat="server" Height="23px" Width="189px" AutoPostBack="True">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: What isn't working. Please explain the problem. Also, posting the code for the post backs would be useful.

Comment: Post your code in `DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged`

Answer (score 1):

I copied your code as it is, and gave definition to selected index changed event as

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
     ListItem li = new ListItem("text");
     ddlDistrict.Items.Add(li);
}
```

and it worked beautifully. You might have some other issue. Can you copy your selected index changed event code?